# About R ggplot2 could not plot correct graph in for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new in R. I encounter some troubles.

The dataset is like this:[stats.stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQXy6.png)

I want to produce many graphs for every variable by (x = date, y = variable).

This is my code:

```
stat.variables <- names(stats.stock)
stat.variables <- stat.variables[-1]
for (i in stat.variables) {

   png(filename =paste0("C:\\Users\\", i, "stock.jpg"), width=2400, height=1800, res=300)
   print(ggplot(stats.stock, 
          mapping = aes_string(
            x = "Date", 
            y = i)) + geom_point())
   dev.off()
}
```

However, results turn out like this:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vZ3a.png)

I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my data. If I run only one variable, the result is good.
[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/735zM.png)

How could I deal with this trouble? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `aes` instead of `aes_string` as it is deprecated and make use of `.data` to subset the column

```
for (i in stat.variables) {

  png(filename =paste0("C:\\Users\\", i, "stock.png"), 
           width=2400, height=1800, res=300)
  print(ggplot(stats.stock, 
          mapping = aes(
            x = Date, 
            y = .data[[i]])) +
                  geom_point())
   dev.off()
}
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
wd <- getwd()
data(iris)
iris$Date <- seq(Sys.Date(), length.out = nrow(iris), by = '1 day')
stat.variables <- names(iris)[1:4]
for (i in stat.variables) {

  png(filename = file.path(wd,  paste0(i, "_stock.png")), 
           width=2400, height=1800, res=300)
  print(ggplot(iris, 
          mapping = aes(
            x = Date, 
            y = .data[[i]])) +
                  geom_point())
   dev.off()
}
```

-output

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Jacy one more typo I found is that you were using `.jpg` with `png` call, which I corrected